# Remove ComPort from current ports after it has been disconnected - C#

Tags: c#, exception, serial-port, port, com-port

I have an app that manages multiple serialports. It should show what ports are currently connected. For detecting the current ports I use `SerialPort.GetPortNames();`. This works fine, if the port is closed before it is removed. However, if the port is disconnected before being closed, `SerialPort.GetPortnames();` still returns it, even if it is closed and disposed after. Is there any way to remove the port after it has been physically disconnected?

Code:

```cs
try
{
      // Read from the port.
}
catch(OperationCanceledException e) // This exception is thrown when the port is disconnected.
{
     // Stop other tasks
     _port.Close();
     _port.Dispose();
}
```

PS: I am aware of the similarities to the question [SerialPort.GetPortNames() behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754857/serialport-getportnames-behavior) but the solution does not seem to work for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9837330/17034